# Chrome Extension - Cancel Publish

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

we submitted updates to our extension last night and realized after submitting that it has a typo. It's currently in "pending review" state and has two options 1. "Cancel Publish" 2. "Unpublish".  Pretty clear what unpublish will do but not sure what cancel publish does. Will it just cancel the current submission for review but still keep the last approved version in the store? [image: CurrentOptions]

Not able to find any help docs or resources on the "Cancel Publish" option and would appreciate any help. Thanks much.

Comment: That's a brand new option with no associated documentation. You should cancel publish and let us know what it does.

Comment: Sounds like it... cancels publishing.

Comment: Update. I just hit the "Cancel Publish" button and it did what it says. Phew. It canceled the submission without affecting the current published version in the store.

Answer (score 7):

This feature in the Chrome Store dev console is one of the most dangerous I know of.
As far I know, from my personal experience and reading some posts from super-upset users, here is how it works :

### Clicking "Cancel Publish"

This will delete a draft version of your extension that has already been approved by Google but not yet published by you. You can always re-submit the version if you clicked by mistake.

**Biggest consequence possible : you will lose some time on your update**  (up to a few weeks depending on how long the new review takes for your extension.)

### ⚠️ Clicking "Unpublish"

This will ⚠️**remove your extension from the entire Chrome Store**⚠️ with dramatic consequences for your users. And Google will not be able to easily revert this.

**Biggest consequence possible : all your users will have your extension uninstalled automatically and you will no longer appear in the store**. Restoring service will take a lot of time (resubmitting to Google) and some data will be forever lost (reviews, ranking, etc.)

====

### Side Note

If you think this is crazy, wait until you seen the French version :
[image]

Yes, we have two buttons "Annuler la publication" (literally "cancel publication"). One with dramatic consequences for your extension... And it's up to you to choose which one to click.

Comment: *This will delete a draft version of your extension that has already been approved by Google but not yet published by you. You can always re-submit the version (though the version number needs to be different) if you clicked by mistake.* You can use the same version number of the draft you Cancel Publish. Done it two times in the past, and today. Was incrementing it before, now I don't, as I want my Chrome extension's version number to be in sync with Microsoft Edge and App Store

Comment: OK. I'm editing the answer then